# JSF 2.0: @ResourceDependency does not work when adding UIComponent programmatically

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

```
@ResourceDependency(library = "component/myComponent", name = "myComponent1.css")
public class MyComponent1 extends UIComponentBase {

    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        MyComponent2 comp2 = new MyComponent2();
        getChildren().add(comp2);
    }

}

@ResourceDependency(library = "component/myComponent", name = "myComponent2.css")
public class MyComponent2 extends UIComponentBase {

    // ...

}
```

`myComponent1.css` gets included into page, `myComponent2.css` does not.

Feature? Bug? Configuration issue?

It there programmatic way to add resources to maybe workaround this?

Running Mojarra 2.0.2

Comment: I traced this a bit further. It seems that JSF doesn't find (=search for) the annotations of the programmatically added component, thus they don't have any effect. Looking at the JSF/Mojarra code, there seems to be multiple paths to creating component. I suppose creating component via tag handler does annotation lookup in a different way than when programmatic approach. I am going to report this as an issue to Mojarra tracker for their closer inspection if nobody stands out to correct me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this was asked 10 months ago, but I've been facing this same issue. Your resource problem here is caused by the fact that you are using "new" to instantiate your child component. Instead, you should use `context.getApplication().createComponent("MyComponentType")`,
"MyComponentType" being whatever you specified as the value in @FacesComponent annotation. The application parses the annotations while it creates the component, not when it is rendering. Using `new` deprives the application from it's opportunity to handle the annotations. Unfortunately, this doesn't actually resolve the issue, it should, but it doesn't.

If you add:

```
UIComponent headFacet = context.getViewRoot().getFacet("javax_faces_location_HEAD");
if (headFacet == null) {
    System.out.println("No Head Facet");
} else {
    System.out.println("Head Children: " + headFacet.getChildCount());
    for (UIComponent c : headFacet.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(c.getRendererType());
        System.out.println(c.getAttributes().get("name"));
    }
}
```

to your encodeBegin method you will be able to see that the Resources have actually been added (example adding the PrimeFaces FileUpload as a child):

```
INFO: Head Children: 4
INFO: javax.faces.resource.Stylesheet
INFO: fileupload/fileupload.css
INFO: javax.faces.resource.Script
INFO: jquery/jquery.js
INFO: javax.faces.resource.Script
INFO: core/core.js
INFO: javax.faces.resource.Script
INFO: fileupload/fileupload.js
```

unfortunately, they still never get rendered, it is as if the component has a different view root than the page it is ultimately rendered on. I'm still looking into this further before report any bugs. I am currently running mojarra 2.0.6, I may try it on 2.2 to see if the issue is resolved.

**Update:** Tested on Mojarra 2.1.3 and 2.2-SNAPSHOT. It does not work on either. I have added an [issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2231) to the Mojarra Issue Tracker

**Update Again:** The people over at Mojarra have informed me that the encodeBegin is not the place to try adding components. They have pointed me to this [blog](http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2010/10/safely-manipulating-component-tree-with.html) posting, which describes how to "safely" do it.

Comment: You have clearly done better reserach here. I checked the ticket (can't remember if I ever created one myself) and the blog bost. I agree with you, the required approach is very unintuitive, or, well, maybe even intuitive *if* you knew the whole JSF spec. But then, many issue in JSF is unintuitive, so guess I should've expected this. Picking as the accepted answer, thanks for sharing even after 10 months :)